# Get basic profile info from google-api-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the ruby `google-api-client` gem. I'm able to successfully OAuth and get back a access token. For the life of me, now that I have the token, I can't figure out how to get the basic profile info for the user.

My scope includes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. How do I get this info from the client, or what google client library should I pull in to get this info?

Any help appreciated...this seems like a really simple request, yet I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'google/apis/oauth2_v2'
service = Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new
service.tokeninfo(access_token: "Your Access Token").email
```

[Source code here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/39ae3527722a003b389a2f7f5275ab9c6e93bb5e/generated/google-apis-oauth2_v2/lib/google/apis/oauth2_v2/service.rb)

Comment: embed the link using markdown and add a meaningful word. It will look good and also meaningful [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)... Like this